# Create a Class for Reused UILabels

Tags: iphone, xcode, uilabel

I find myself creating essentially the same UILabel repeatedly in my app. So I'm thinking this is a good time to create a class for it and just call the class?

For example, I reuse this code many times to create a UILabel for my UINavigationBar in views, with the only difference being the label.text that I'm thinking I can pass as a parameter:

```
// - - - - - Add a Navigation Bar

UINavigationBar *navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
navBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack; 
navBar.translucent = YES;

[self.view addSubview:navBar];
[navBar release];

// - - - - - Add a label to the navbar

UILabel *navLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,8,280,30)];
navLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
navLabel.text = @"Some Label String";
navLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
navLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
navLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20];
navLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.5];
navLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
[navBar addSubview:navLabel];
[navLabel release];
```

So I'm thinking I should be able to create a UILabelNavBar Class and simply create the UILabel by calling it like this:

```
navBar addSubview:[UILabelNavBar createLabel:@"Some Label String"]];
```

Except I don't know how to create the class. 
Any help is appreciated.
lq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the nudge from Adubr, the following works:

```
// *** OftenUsedLabel.h ***

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface OftenUsedLabel : UILabel 
{
    UILabel *oftenUsedLabel;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *oftenUsedLabel;

@end

// *** OftenUsedLabel.m ***

#import "OftenUsedLabel.h"

@implementation OftenUsedLabel

@synthesize oftenUsedLabel;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    if (self) {

        CGRect rect;
        rect = CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,280.0,30.0);

        oftenUsedLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
        oftenUsedLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        oftenUsedLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        oftenUsedLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20];
        oftenUsedLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.5];
        oftenUsedLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;

        [self addSubview:oftenUsedLabel];
    }

    return self;    
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [oftenUsedLabel release];
    [super dealloc];
}


// *** SomeViewController.m ***

#import "OftenUsedLabel.h"

// CALL THE LABEL LIKE THIS:

    CGRect rect;
    rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 60.0);
    UILabel *myLabel = [[[OftenUsedLabel alloc] initWithFrame:rect] autorelease];
    myLabel.text = @"Some Text";
    [self.view addSubview:myLabel];
    [myLabel release];
```

Comment: Hi Lauren Quantrell thanks for your answer. But if I have to use OftenUsedLabel in 50 view controller then I Have to create 50 instance of  OftenUsedLabel. Is there any way by which i can create only one instance of OftenUsedLabel

Answer (score 3):

File -> New file... -> Objective C class -> UIView subclass -> enter the name of the class -> choose folder -> change UIView in just created .m and .h files to UILabel

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a class here. Just define function like `addLabel(UINavigationBar *navBar, ... text)` and use it.

Answer (score -2):

What language are creating this in? (Looks abit like XAML/WPF to me...or FLEX?)

Generally speaking the syntax would be as follows:

```
Class NavBar()
{

   function navBar()
   {
      //new navbar object
      UINavigationBar *navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] 
      initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,          320, 44)];
      navBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack; 
      navBar.translucent = YES;

      [self.view addSubview:navBar];
      [navBar release];

      //call the navbar function and create the label for the new navbar
      navBarLabel()

   }

   function navBarLabel()
   {

      UILabel *navLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,8,280,30)];
      navLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
      navLabel.text = @"Some Label";
      navLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
      navLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
      navLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20];
      navLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.5];
      navLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
      [navBar addSubview:navLabel];
      [navLabel release];         

   }

}
```

But depends on the programming language and possibly platform too. :) Also if you create it as an external class and make it public, you should be able to call these functions whenever you need them.

So for example the navBar could be created without calling the navBar label...then the user can decide to input something for this new label or not. If they do not input anything the program goes on to the next method, or the user creates a new label.

It will be a dynamic and more interactive system. :)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. mine is Objective-C, thus the iPhone and xcode tags in my post.

Comment: Found out how to do it yet? Think you best work in objects and functions as I explained for future extensibility.                        DL.

Comment: Ahhh Objective-C...OOP'd version of C. So what are you developing...some touch screen multimedia app? DL